# WPF: font (size) renders differently on XP and Vista/7

Tags: wpf, fonts, windows-xp, rendering, font-size

The code is pretty much straightforward:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding TimeAgo}" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" Background="Transparent"/>
```

As far as I know, WPF has native support for Calibri font. However, the font renders differently on XP and on Vista/7:

XP:
[image]

Vista: 
[image]

My main issue is with the font's size (It renders bigger on XP) since I have dedicated, limited space for the text.

I am currently using UseLayoutRounding="True" but removing it didn't make any difference. I'm also using:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
```

But removing it also didn't make any difference (In terms of the font's size).

Comment: Are the XP and 7 on the same machine? If so, are they using the same resolution?

Comment: Vista SP2 @ 1920x1200, XP SP3 @ 1280x1024. Both are running .NET v4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF does not have native support for any font, it can only use the fonts installed on the machine.

The bigger text is not Calibri (it looks like Arial or Tahoma to me), you can look at the shape of the "g" to see those are not the same font.

You can only use Calibri on XP if you or another software (like Office 2007 or later) installed it first.

Comment: Well spotted on the shape of the "g". I missed that completely.

Comment: Oh, is there an easy way to include it with the rest of the assemblies?

Comment: @tutipute - Usually you must buy a license to distribute a font with your app (even if its for your own app only), I don't know the rules about Calibri, if you have the rights to embed the font just follow those steps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx or those if you want to do it in Blend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296385.aspx